# How to add ripple effect when clicking Card in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Is there a way I can add ripple effect to Material UI [`Card`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-card/) component on click.

And I would also like to know, is it possible to make ripple effect to come on top of the content of Card component, rather that it showing as background.

Comment: With materialize-css, you're able to add the "wave" effect to seemingly any element (http://materializecss.com/waves.html#!). I haven't tested this out, but looks up your alley.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can see this question was not answered, so I'll provide an up-to-date solution (writing this as `material-ui` is v. 0.18.7 (stable):

You need to import the ripple higher-order comp. (HOC) as:

`import TouchRipple from '@material-ui/core/ButtonBase/TouchRipple';`

Then you can wrap any component of you choice with `TouchRipple`, like:

```
<TouchRipple>
   <div>
     MY RIPPLING DIV
   </div>
</TouchRipple>
```

Or, if you need a CSS class-based apporach, you can use materialize lib -> https://react-materialize.github.io/#/

In that case, it's as simple as adding a value to `waves` prop on a material-ui `Button`, like:

`<Button waves='light'>EDIT ME<Icon left>save</Icon></Button>`

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/internal/TouchRipple'

Comment: Thanks! just one thing: Now the Ripple is located in '@material-ui/core/ButtonBase/TouchRipple';

Answer (score 25):

I noticed that TouchRipple has been moved out of the `internal` directory.
It's now available in the [ButtonBase folder](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/v1-beta/src/ButtonBase).

Here is how I was able to add ripple effect by using the ButtonBase component -

Basically, you wrap your component, let's say `<Card>` inside the `<ButtonBase>` like so, and the `ButtonBase` takes care of the `TouchRipple` setting up for you -

```
<ButtonBase>
     <Card>
         ....
     </Card>
</ButtonBase>
```

Here is a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zn8kvr59jl) link to working demo.
I know this is not the best way. You could directly use the `TouchRipple`/`Ripple`  component, but I found this way to be very easy to use.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

#### **2021 Update**

The most idiomatic way to add the ripple effect when clicking the `Card` is using the [`CardActionArea`](https://mui.com/api/card-action-area/#inheritance). [This component](https://mui.com/components/cards/#primary-action) inherits the props of `ButtonBase`. It also changes the `Card` background color when hovered and focused (unlike `ButtonBase`):

```
<Card>
  <CardActionArea>
    <CardContent>
      {...}
    </CardContent>
  </CardActionArea>
</Card>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: `CardActionArea` can also be used outside cards to add the ripple effect to `div`s

Answer (score 3):

## Using MUI V5 (2022)

You can get the benefit of the `component` prop, use the `<ButtonBase>` component to get the ripple effect.

Create a React HOC or simply copy this code into a new file:

```js
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react'
import { ButtonBase } from '@mui/material'

export default function WithTouchRipple(OriginalComponent) {
  return (props) => {
    const Wrapper = !props.component
      ? ButtonBase
      : forwardRef((ButtonBaseProps, ref) => <ButtonBase component={props.component} {...ButtonBaseProps} ref={ref} />)
    return <OriginalComponent {...props} component={Wrapper} />
  }
}
```

Then use it as follows on any component you like:

```
import { Chip, Card, Stack } from '@mui/material'
import WithTouchRipple from '../WithTouchRipple'

const RippleChip = WithTouchRipple(Chip)
const RippleCard = WithTouchRipple(Card)
const RippleStack = WithTouchRipple(Stack)
```

```
<RippleChip component={Link} to={`/users/${id}`} {...chipProps} />
<RippleStack>...</RippleStack>
<RippleCard>...</RippleCard>
```

---

If you want the ripple effect to appear on the `<Card>` component, there is a built-in component for that called `<CardActionArea>`, and you can use it as follows:

```
<Card>
  <CardActionArea>
    <CardContent>
      {...}
    </CardContent>
  </CardActionArea>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach taken in @xiaofan2406 never worked for me, not to mention passing height, width and position seems easily breakable and might not be possible when using flexbox.

However I managed to make it work like:

```
<YourComponent>
    <TouchRipple>
        {children}
    </TouchRipple>
</YourComponent>
```

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work, I've added `TouchRipple` and use it around my component, but ripple creates at the top left corner of the page, which is obviuosly not the mentioned behaviour.

Comment: Are the items inside absolutely positioned? bare into account material-ui calculates a lot of the properties on runtime, so you should take a look at the actual children representation, in any case, it worked for me and taking a look at the source code of material-ui components this is how it is being used

Comment: I'm not sure about absolutely positioned items, however, I'm using ripple like this: `<TouchRipple><Card>...</Card></TouchRipple>` and it doesn't work.

Comment: I have no idea of <Card> component internal workings, this is working when wrapping non-material ui components, my advice is: take a look at the source code of <Card> the children prop is probably being not being calculated the way you expect

My second suggestion: <Card><TouchRipple>...</TouchRipple></Card>

Answer (score 1):

## Here is a Solution 2021 updated

1. simple You need wrap your custom components with  component from material ui .
2. Then add style padding: 0 that solve.
3. Here I want my  Image should react with ripple effect.

**You can customize by wrapping with Grid and props container**

```js
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

function ImageCard(props){

return (
            <Button style={{ padding: 0, borderRadius: "16px" }}>
              {/*my custom component you can use any component even material ui component also*/}
                <img
                  src={yourImageUrl}
                  alt="img"
                  style={{
                    height: 200,
                    width: 400,
                    borderRadius: "16px",//optional
                  }}
                />
              </Button>
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using `component` attribute

Instead of wrapping, you can specify the `component` attribute as the desired component you want it to be. That is, for this use-case;

```
import ButtonBase from '@material-ui/core/ButtonBase';
...
<Card component = {ButtonBase}>
  <CardContent>
    ...
  </CardContent>
</Card>
```

If you have issues with height or width of the card, add the `sx` attribute;

```
<Card component={ButtonBase} sx={{height:'100%', width:'100%'}}>
   ...
</Card>
```

If ButtonBase messes up all other buttons on the page, it's better to use just the Button;

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
...
<Card component = {Button}>
  <CardContent>
    ...
  </CardContent>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

The official api doesn't seem to support it. 
But this is what I do, when I want to use `material-ui` ripple affect:

Use `material-ui/internal/TouchRipple`, have a look at its [source code](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/5d5128d251816bfccec0cb305a48ec553c399c4e/src/internal/TouchRipple.js)

Usage example:

```
<YourComponent>
    <TouchRipple style={style}/>
    {children}
</YourComponent>
```

You need to pass the inline style to specify its height, width and position that matches `YourComponent`'s height, width and postion

Comment: I have been trying to make this work for the last 2 hours or so, but doesn't work, apparently the onTouchTap propagation does not reach the underlaying TouchRipple component, I tried to manually pass the event, but that does not seem to work either... any suggestions?

Comment: Just fyi, I have read the source code and that is how I knew I had to manually pass the onTouchTap even to handleOnMouseDown, but it still does not work

Comment: @das_franco `TouchRipple` doesn't have any `onTouchTap` or `handleOnMouseDown`. [See here](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/5d5128d251816bfccec0cb305a48ec553c399c4e/src/internal/TouchRipple.js#L11-L18)